# No text appended to text file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, text-files, openpyxl

The script appears to run without error, though no output is visible in the text file (despite the fact i can see the file has been edited by the date modified). I am very new to python so apologies for any obvious errors. Thanks for your help.

I was originally using xlrd but changed to openpyxl due to possible incompatibility with .xlsm files (is this true)

```
def list_files(directory, extension):
    from os import listdir
    return (f for f in listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.' + extension))

def scrape(xlpath, name, crit, row, column):
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    directory = os.getcwd()
    #discover values
    loc = xlpath
    wb = load_workbook(loc)
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name)
    place = row+","+column
    data = sheet.cell(place).value
    #transfer to text file
    print("\n ", crit, " : ", data.cells.value, file=open("info.txt", "a"))

def presenting(pth):
    scrape(pth, 'generic val1', 'Sheet1', '7', '1')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val2',  'Sheet1', '0', '1')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val3', 'Sheet1', '8', '1')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val4', 'Sheet1', '29', '4')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val5', 'Sheet2', '21', '6')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val6', 'Sheet2', '22', '6')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val7', 'Sheet2', '56', '19')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val8', 'Sheet2', '56', '20')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val9', 'Sheet2', '56', '21')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val10', 'Sheet2', '36', '14')
    scrape(pth, 'generic val11', 'Sheet2', '37', '14')

def process():
    import os
    directory = os.getcwd()
    files = list_files(directory, "xlsm")
    for f in files:
        pth = str(f)
        print("\n", pth, file=open("info.txt", "a"))
        presenting(pth)

import os
directory = os.getcwd()
open('info.txt', 'w').close()
process()
```

Expected results is a list of generic variables and their respective values retrieved from the all excel files in local folder (working directory). Actual results is only the name of the first (of 3) excel files in the local folder.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don´t write into the file. You only open the file with `open` and thats all. You never write or close it.

And a tip:
Just write `import os` at the beginning of your file. So you don´t need to import it several times.